# Django Form Not Displaying in Template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to create an "edit profile" page/form and have followed the SimpleIsBetterThanComplex tutorial on how to extend the user model by way of the OneToOne Link. However, when i try to display the user profile form to allow the user to update their profile, the form doesn't display at all except for the Submit button... Any ideas where i might have gone wrong here?

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils import timezone

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #account types
    is_userA = models.BooleanField('User A', default=True)
    is_userB = models.BooleanField('User B', default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField('SuperUser', default=False)

    #other fields here
    avatar = models.ImageField('avatar', upload_to='static/media/images/avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField('phone number', max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    address = models.CharField('address', max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    city = models.CharField('city', max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    state = models.CharField('state', max_length=2, default='', blank=True)
    country = models.CharField('country', max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
    })
```

**template**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="mb32">
    <h5 class="uppercase">General Information</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: show your template

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy added template code to original post

Comment: Do you mean form not rendering or you can see first name, last name and email field and don't see profile's field such as avatar, phone, etc?

Comment: The form isnt rendering at all. The only thing i see is a Submit button.

Comment: @Nick it's very weird. I just tried the same in my project and everything working fine. Could you check template? Is it possible that there is another template named profile.html?

Comment: I just think, about last `else` statement, try to do indent in the last `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Your view looks for now looks like this:
**views.py**

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
    })
```

According to this view if method POST, you validate enterd data from the form, but when its GET method you just define `UserForm`, so i think you have to make indent in the last line:
**views.py**

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
    })
```

So your last line `return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {'user_form': user_form,})` have to be under `else` statement, cause its `GET` as I understand.